# Browserify context when setting a prototype self executing function with require

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, require

I have a "class" like so:

```
function Person(params) {
   this.params = params;
}
```

and I would like to define prototypes like this:

```
Person.prototype.talk = require("./talk.js")(options);
```

and inside talk.js:

```
module.exports = exports = function(options) {

     console.log(this); // window here not person

     return {};
};
```

but inside talk.js `this` is not referring to the new Person object created...
the context is window

This has to do because the require is being passed some settings...
Is there any way to pass / preserve the context inside talk.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to the `require(...)` call, it's related to *when* and *how* the exported function is called.

When you do

```
Person.prototype.talk = require("./talk.js")(options);
```

you're "requiring" (importing...) the code from "talk.js", which is a function, which you the immediately invoke with a parameter (`options`), but without any context object so the default (`window`) is used.

What you apparently want is to have an instance available as the `this` inside the function, but at the time you call it, there is no instance of the `Person` class available.

When you'll later call `talk()` on an instance, an instance will exist as the `this` value.

If you want `talk` to be the logging function, simply set it in the prototype **without invoking it**:

```
Person.prototype.talk = require("./talk.js");

// later...
var p = new Person("some parameter");
p.talk("some option"); // <- this will log the instance.
```